# Spring XD Job runs on Job Deployment

Tags: spring-batch, spring-xd

I have a Spring batch Job with a tasklet Step and it get run when I deploy the Job to Spring XD. I want my job to run only when I launch my Job. Is this the default behavior or something I messed up?

```
<batch:job id='firstJob' restartable="false">
    <batch:step id="myDAO">
        <batch:tasklet ref="myDAOTasklet" />
        <batch:next on="NO_RECORD" to="jobFinish" />
        <batch:next on="*" to="nextStep" />
    </batch:step>
```

Comment: How are you packaging your job?

Comment: It's a custom module jar

Comment: Do you have Spring Boot's auto config enabled?  If so, it will try to launch the job when the context is created.  You can either turn it off or configure the job not to run on startup via the Spring Boot documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-execute-spring-batch-jobs-on-startup

Comment: Awesome!! I had @EnableAutoConfiguration in my code. It worked after I removed that. I would have no clue why this was happening. Thanks much !!